# Is there a way I can combine multiple collapsible elements one jquery function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have several collapsible elements on my page,and they are hidden and shown using jquery's .toggleClass() function.  However, if they have the same ID, only one of the elements will work.  It functions now, but I feel like there has to be a much better way of going about this, as it feels kinda clunky.

Here is the HTML for the two elements:

```
        <div>
            <h1 id="collapseGallery">Contemporary Issues in Painting: Digital Media</h1>
            <div id="galleryImg" class="hide">
                <?php include 'imagesCIPD.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <h1 id="collapseGallery2">Contemporary Issues in Painting: Traditional Media</h1>
            <div id="galleryImg2" class="hide">
                <?php include 'imagesCIPT.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the JS

```
$('#collapseGallery').ready(function () {
    $('#collapseGallery').click(function () {
        $('#galleryImg').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});

$('#collapseGallery2').ready(function () {
    $('#collapseGallery2').click(function () {
        $('#galleryImg2').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to only have one ID, i.e. #collapseGallery, and then use that for multiple collapsible elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ID, give them all the same class, and you can select them that way. Also, for the easiest path to find the appropriate image div to collapse, you can add that element's ID as a data attribute to the  you're clicking.

```
<h1 id="collapseGallery1" class="collapse" data-image-id="galleryImg1">...
<h1 id="collapseGallery2" class="collapse" data-image-id="galleryImg2">...
```

Then you just need this in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse').click(function() {
        var imgId = $(this).attr('data-image-id');

        $('#' + imgId).toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```